# Disconnect local branch from remote one

Tags: git, branch, remote-branch

I have two local branches A and B tracking the same remote branch C. I want to keep all the branches but I want to remove connection A -> C but keep the connection B -> C. how can i do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the asaociaton between the local and remote branch

```
git config --unset branch.<local branch A>.remote
git config --unset branch.<local branch A>.merge
```

---

Alternatively in your project's `.git/config` file remove the `merge` statement corresponding to the branch `A`.

---

Alternatively you can create a new branch `D` from `A`, and then delete the original branch `A` if needed.

```
git checkout A
git checkout -b D

#Delete A if needed
git branch -D A
```

Comment: As of git 1.8, you have another variant to remove the association:

`git branch --unset-upstream A`